# Clarify [rad] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We have 2 tags [rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rad) and [ibm-rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rad) which are related to IBM Rational Application Developer. I see it confuses some users as rad in general relates to Rapid Application Development, various IDEs that support 'rapid' development.

I'd suggest:

- retag questions related to IBM RAD to [ibm-rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rad)
- change the [rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rad) tag to have general description of Rapid Application Development tools, not IBM Rational Application Developer.

Comment: Just edit the wiki to say "Please don't use this tag".

Comment: @HansPassant why you dont want to just change description of the `rad` tag?

Comment: Because SO users should not use the tag.  They will anyway but you can at least slow them down a bit.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant - RAD, in the Rapid Application Development retro-90s sense - adds nothing to an on-topic SO question.

Comment: Note that you'll also see [tag:rad] used in place of [tag:rad-studio], which is *itself* deprecated in favor of [tag:delphi] or [tag:c++builder].

Comment: New Title: "Wouldn't it be [rad] to update [rad]?"